# For what T does `std::declval<T>()` not have a matching function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declval

I was surprised to find that for some `T`, `decltype(std::declval<T>())` is not legal:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
using Alias = decltype(std::declval<T>());

// as expected
using A1 = Alias<int>;
using A2 = Alias<int(int)>;

// error: no matching function for call to 'declval<...>()'
using A3 = Alias<int(int) const>;
using A4 = Alias<int(int) volatile>;
using A5 = Alias<int(int) &>;
using A6 = Alias<int(int) &&>;
// and all combinations of the above
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) doesn't seem to indicate that this error is expected.

Are there any other types for which `declval<T>` cannot be used? Where does the spec define these?

Comment: Putting attributes after function prototype type seems to throw an error. You may have to use `std::function` over the types: `Alias<std::function<int(int)> const>`

Comment: @D.Nathanael That alters semantics.  `std::function` is about type erasure.

Comment: `std::function<int(int)> const` is the analog to `int(const*)(int)`, not to `int(*)(int) const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [[declval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/declval), the signature of `declval` is:

```
template <class T>
add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;
```

Therefore, the call is ill-formed if `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` cannot occur as a return type specifier.

Qualified function types have a special rule:

> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier*
>   (including a type named by *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param])) shall appear only as:
>
> - (6.1) the function type for a non-static member function,
> - (6.2) the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - (6.3) the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*,
> - (6.4) the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter*, or
> - (6.5) the *type-id* of a template-argument for a *type-parameter* ([temp.arg.type]).

They cannot be a return type specifier.

Looking through [Types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type), I'm pretty sure qualified function types are the only case.